# Run Hive Query in R with Config

Tags: r, hadoop, hive

I'm able to successfully connect and run queries in R from Hive using library(DBI) and library(RJDBC)

However, I'm trying to set the following config

```
 Set hive.execution.engine=mr;
```

When I try to use the following command (which is how I would query), I get an error:

```
 dbGetQuery(conn_expp_team, "Set hive.execution.engine=mr")
```

Here is the error:

```
 Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
 Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for Set hive.execution.engine=mr (The query did not generate a result set!)
```

Comment: Maybe `dbSendQuery` will be better. `dbGetQuery` (as the name and error message suggests) is for retrieving results.

Comment: @Marek - just tried that and got the same error "The query did not generate a result set!"

Comment: Same here. dbGetQuery just calls dbSendQuery. It probably expects a result object even if there are no results so that it can do double duty.

Comment: boils down to RJDBC using executeQuery method vs execute. Entered a ticket with RJDBC. I fully expect them saying not their problem, understandably. It works with N+1 databases.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RJDBC::dbSendUpdate(conn, statement)`. Source: https://github.com/s-u/RJDBC/issues/25